# SQL Union multiple tables - Where substring(table_name) = x

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Microsoft's Dynamics NAV has a feature where each SQL table-name is preceded by the name of a company, i.e.

- Company1$G_L Entry
- Company2$G_L Entry
- Company3$G_L Entry
- Company4$G_L Entry
- etc...

I'd like to create UNION ALL (the table columns/types are identical) for all tables ending in '$G_L Entry', that is, without specifying all the tables.

This is because, at any time, the user of the NAV UI may add/remove companies, and I'd prefer not to update my query every time that happens.

Any directions much appreciated.

(Using SQL Server 2012)

Comment: You should fix your data structure so the company GL entries are stored in a single table.  Much more efficient, easier to maintain, and to query.

Comment: [Dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) will do it

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not always possible...

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Unfortunately I cannot influence the setup of this NAV instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build dynamic sql by concatenating your table names with a union all (obviously you'd need to list the columns)

```
DECLARE @allEntryTables VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @allEntryTables = ( SELECT
                         STUFF((SELECT
                                 ' UNION ALL SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ' + name
                                FROM sys.tables
                                WHERE name LIKE '%$G_L Entry'
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 11, ''));

EXEC (@allEntryTables);
```

Comment: That's awesome. I added square brackets as well, since NAV also creates table names full of spaces,including leading and trailing....

Comment: `DECLARE @allEntryTables VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @allEntryTables = (
  SELECT STUFF((
     SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) * FROM [' + NAME + ']'
     FROM sys.tables
     WHERE NAME LIKE '%$G_L Entry'
     FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 11, '')
  );

EXEC (@allEntryTables);
`

Answer (score 0):

im guessing you dont know how many tables you have, and then you need to specify the table list first.
you can select sys tables. 
eg: "SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE '%$G_L' and INSERT table names into temp 
and here's your table list.